# Button click rotation js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My html

```
<div id="yabanner">
  <img src="img/ok.jpg">
</div>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

My javascript

```
 var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var button1 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1];
var button2 = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[2];
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

  button1.addEventListener('click', slid , false);

  function slid(e) {
    image.src="img/kok.jpg";
    image.style.display="block";

  }
button.addEventListener('click' , fillIt , false );

  function fillIt(e) {
    image.src="img/ok.jpg";
    image.style.display="block";

  }


button2.addEventListener('click' , show ,false);

function show(e) {
image.src="img/rm2.jpg";
image.style.display="block";
}
```

Can someone help me how to finish this .
I want to make a img rotate when u click one of the button.I tried other method but doesn't work if someone needs it let me know :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use something in your function(s) like:

```
image.style.transform: "rotate(90deg)"
```

You can use `-90deg` for the other direction. You can undo it all with `image.removeAttribute('style')`